# Error "Kernel already used" when using trained RNN to make prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, prediction, recurrent-neural-network

Thanks for looking into this question!

I am trying to train an LSTM network which predicts the next 5-day stock prices based on past 30-day stock prices. I have trained the model based on 265 samples. The variables are defined as follow:

```
# Variables
x = tf.placeholder("float", [265, 30])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [265, 5])

weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, y_size]))
    }

biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([y_size]))
    }
```

and the model looks as below:

```
# Define RNN architecture
def RNN(x, weights, biases):
    x_size = 30
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, x_size])
    x = tf.split(x, x_size, 1)

    rnn_cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell([rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden), rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden)])

    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(rnn_cell, x, dtype = tf.float32)

    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out'] + biases['out'])
```

Then, I attempt to use the trained model to predict as follow:

```
y_pred = RNN(x_input, trained_weights, trained_biases)
```

in which x_input has a dimension (1x30). In gave me a list of error which I could not understand:

```
ValueError: Variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1654, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3290, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\teh.khoonkheng\Desktop\Others\Personal working folder\14. Projects\1. Oracle\Python\RNN_stock_01.py", line 135, in <module>
    y_test = RNN(x_test, trained_weights, trained_biases)
  File "C:\Users\teh.khoonkheng\Desktop\Others\Personal working folder\14. Projects\1. Oracle\Python\RNN_stock_01.py", line 81, in RNN
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(rnn_cell, x, dtype = tf.float32)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 1330, in static_rnn
    (output, state) = call_cell()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 1317, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 191, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 714, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1242, in call
    cur_inp, new_state = cell(cur_inp, cur_state)
```

I was wondering if I have misunderstood how static_rnn works. Have I set up the model incorrectly? And how should I use the trained RNN to make prediction?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says, you need to mention `reuse=True` such that the learned states can be used later for prediction. Do this:

```
rnn_cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell([rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden,reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE), rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden,reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)])
```

Also, this model looks wrong because, while you're using the trained `weights` and `biases`, but you're not using the trained `LSTMcells`. For new inputs, you're defining new `LSTMcells`.

Comment: Thanks @mkst for your response! How should I amend the code such that I can use the trained LSTMcells as well as the trained weights & biases in making prediction?